# control pc through ethernet line

Tags: ethernet, remote

I have my desktop setup with internet and have an Ethernet connection to my Raspberry Pi, using network sharing the Pi can access the internet.

Can I use the Ethernet line to control the Pi with my keyboard and mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) to control all my desktops and laptops in the same LAN with the main keyboard and mouse. I'm assuming you have some desktop installed in the Pi, like Ubuntu or Debian.

Also, if you just want access trough commandline, install openssh-server and openssh-client in the Pi, and you can log-in using the IP in the LAN.

Comment: I got to say that works amazingly. love it.